# TeamCity Git clone parameters

Tags: git, teamcity

Is it possible to add parameters to the git clone operation performed by TeamCity as a first step of a CI pipeline? I would like to add "-c core.longpaths=true".
How to do it?

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this but you're going to run into other problems most likely. Even if you can coax git to use long path support (POSIX subsystem), any tool you would use to build your code might not support it. The best way is to reduce the length of the paths.

Answer (score 1):

I've found TeamCity's interaction with git to be rather frustrating.  Are you sure it's even doing a `clone` command?  Because in my tests, it doesn't...

Anyway, some options that might suit your need:

You could use manual checkout, and then your checkout process can be whatever you want.  In your build's version control settings you would set the **VCS checkout mode** to **do not checkout files automatically**.  Then you would do your git checkout process in exactly the way you prefer as a first build step.

If that isn't manageable... the other options are kind of hacks.  They do require agent-side checkout, and the steps must be carried out on each agent.

I'm assuming putting the `longpaths` setting in the system config file isn't a viable option (since it would affect all repos on the agent).

One option you could try is to run the job once and use the build log to find the checkout directory; then go to that directory on the agent - which will be a git repo.  Remove everything but the .git directory, and run `git config` to set `longpaths`.  Subsequent builds - so long as they reuse the checkout directory - would hopefully pick up the setting.

Or you could write a wrapper script that adds the argument you want to the command line and calls git.  The VCS root can specify what "git executable" to use, so you can point it to your wrapper.  This works if it's ok to apply the argument to *every* git invocation in the given build - which in your case may be alright.  (If not, you'd have to examine the command line to decide when to apply it.)